# How do I make the Navigation Bar Transparent?

Tags: android, navigation, transparent, android-5.0-lollipop

How do I make the navigation bar transparent in Android Lollipop? In this link it indicates that its possible to make the navigation bar transparent, but I'm not sure how to do it. I don't want it translucent.

http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars

I have tried setting the property

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

But this makes the background of the navigation bar grey in color and the content does not sit behind the navigation bar.

I tried adding the following lines, but it makes the navigation bar translucent, not transparent.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`Set android:windowTranslucentNavigation="true"` in your `styles-v21.xml.`